# Finding average value of field within selected set of points using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, statistics

I have a large set of points in my map and a few masks which create a grid system. I want to find the average value of one field for all the points within each grid square. I already figured out a code to iteratively select each group of points, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get the average for one field out of the points which are selected.

This is the code I have now

```
vert = ['n1','n2','n3','n4','s1anew','s2','s3','s4']

for i in range(8):
    choice = vert[0]
    zone = 0
    for i in range(3):
        arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation('c19w_1983_NAD_XYTableToPoint1', 'WITHIN', (choice),0, 'NEW_SELECTION', 'NOT_INVERT')
        arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation('c19w_1983_NAD_XYTableToPoint1', 'WITHIN', (zone) ,0, 'SUBSET_SELECTION', 'NOT_INVERT')
        print(choice,zone) ##here I will put these in a table (or list) instead of print
        ## here is where I would calculate the average and also put it in the table
        zone = zone + 1
    del vert[0]
```

I ran it and it properly selected the points in each grid

```
n1 0
n1 1
n1 2
n2 0
n2 1
n2 2
n3 0
n3 1
n3 2
n4 0
n4 1
n4 2
s1anew 0
s1anew 1
s1anew 2
s2 0
s2 1
s2 2
s3 0
s3 1
s3 2
s4 0
s4 1
s4 2
```

I feel like this should be simple I just don't know the command and cant find it on the internet

Comment: Do you really need a python script (as a subprocess in a larger procedure)?

Answer (score 4):

The tool you need is "Summary Statistics".

In a Python script, it is the same as the function, `arcpy.analysis.Statistics()`.  For details, see:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm

As with many ArcGIS tool and functions, the documentation for this one states:  "When using layers, only the currently selected features will be used to calculate statistics."

Alternatively, instead of selecting a set at a time, you could make sure that each point had it's grouping as a value in a field.  Then you'd only need to run the statistics once, summarising by that field.

The output of running the statistics is a new table.  You will have to interrogate the table to extract the value(s) you need.

I recommend running it as a tool in ArcGIS Pro to get a feel for how it works and what the output looks like before using it in a script.  This will help you to get the parameters right and help you interpret the results if you're not used to this tool/function.

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS Pro's [Summary Statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm) tool is a very powerful tool, and sometimes the best tool for the job, but I don't see it fitting cleanly into your current approach.  It is probably worth exploring the tool and seeing how you could take a different approach to answering the same question using Summary Statistics, but I will address the question relative to your current approach.

Before getting into ArcGIS/ArcPy, a quick comment on the general code structure.  I am not sure what language you come to Python from, but the flow control code is not very idiomatic for Python.  Specifically, Python's `for` statement can iterate directly over a list so that users don't have to manually retrieve items from a list.  For example, the current code structure of:

```py
>>> vert = ['n1','n2','n3','n4','s1anew','s2','s3','s4']
>>> for i in range(8):
...   choice = vert[0]
...   print(choice)
...   del vert[0]
...
n1
n2
n3
n4
s1anew
s2
s3
s4
>>>
```

can be rewritten as:

```py
>>> vert = ['n1','n2','n3','n4','s1anew','s2','s3','s4']
>>> for choice in vert:
...   print(choice)
...
n1
n2
n3
n4
s1anew
s2
s3
s4
>>>
```

Not only is the rewritten code shorter and more Pythonic in structure, it is also more efficient in terms of runtime execution.  For a list of 8 items, the performance difference is negligible, but it would be noticeable with larger lists.

Getting back to ArcGIS/ArcPy, if you have code that is already working for making selections on layers, then you can use [ArcPy Data Access Cursors](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/get-started/data-access-using-cursors.htm) to dump the values to a list and calculate the average.  Since the name of the field containing values wasn't given, I will just use `ValueField` as a place holder in the code:

```py
vert = ['n1','n2','n3','n4','s1anew','s2','s3','s4']

for choice in vert:
    for zone in range(3):
        arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation('c19w_1983_NAD_XYTableToPoint1', 'WITHIN', (choice),0, 'NEW_SELECTION', 'NOT_INVERT')
        arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation('c19w_1983_NAD_XYTableToPoint1', 'WITHIN', (zone) ,0, 'SUBSET_SELECTION', 'NOT_INVERT')
        print(choice,zone) ##here I will put these in a table (or list) instead of print
        
        values = [value for value, in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('c19w_1983_NAD_XYTableToPoint1', "ValueField")]
        avg = sum(values)/len(values)
        ## here is where I would calculate the average and also put it in the table
```